# How to migrate wordpress to EC2 bitnami?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2, bitnami

**What I want**
Copy the content from an existing wordpress website and move it to another ec2 instance. Content size over 600MB.

**What I have tried so far**:

- created an Amazon EC2 instance and installed Wordpress by Bitnami
- ssh into the the EC2 instance `ssh -i AWS-New-Celleste-Key.pem bitnami@ec2-15-131-31-21.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com`
- installed Duplicator as in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7a0av-94NYo
- successfully downloaded the installer.php and backup zip from the originator site
- using FileZilla, I transferred via sftp the two files from my local pc to `/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs` in the EC2 instance destination

**Question**: is this the folder where I should drop the files?
When I go to `https://www.whatsappneighbours.com/installer.php` I get Page Not Found.

[image]

Comment: To access it at `https://www.whatsappneighbours.com/installer.php` you need to put the files in `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs`

Comment: If you put your comment in an answer I will vote it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access it at `https://www.whatsappneighbours.com/installer.php` you need to put the files in `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs`